# Multiple string matching in Python

Tags: python, regex, string-matching

I am writing an Automation script to extract lines matching the 1st string (inputName) in the logfile and if that particular match is found in that line, searching for 2nd string (successful_msg) in that particular line which says "file is uploaded successfully".

Below is the code :

```
import re

successful_msg="file has been uploaded"
def log_check(fileName):
     search_fileName = fileName
     print search_fileName
     with open("/tmp/test.log") as line:
         for match in line:
                 m=re.search(r"%s" %search_fileName, match)
                 n=re.search(r"%s" %successful_msg,match)
                 if m and n:
                      print match
                 elif m:
                      print "File not updated"
                 else:
                      print "File is not processed"

 for inputName in glob.glob('./files/*'):
    log_check(inputName)
```

I'm able to get the successful message from the "if m and n: "  line. But if I include the "else", I'm seeing only "File is not processed" even though the 1st if passes. Where is the logic going wrong?

Eg: `ls files/`

```
abc-15  abc-16  abc-123  gg
```

My desired output should be :

```
abc-15 
2015-03-17 06:09:26.122  INFO --- *** : The /tmp/test/abc-15 file has been uploaded
abc-16
2015-03-17 06:08:42.692  INFO --- *** : The /tmp/test/abc-16 file has been uploaded
gg
File is not processed
abc-123
File not updated
```

The actual result when else is uncommented/ considered in loop is :

```
gg
File not updated
abc-15
File not updated
abc-16
File not updated
abc-123
File not updated
```

When else is commented, the result is :

```
gg
abc-15
2015-03-17 06:09:26.122  INFO ---*** : The /tmp/test/abc-15 file has been uploaded
abc-16
2015-03-17 06:08:42.692  INFO --- *** : The /tmp/test/abc-16 file has been uploaded
abc-123
```

Comment: Your `for` loop stops if the **first** line from the file does not have your `inputName`, is this *really* what you are expecting?

Comment: No its going through all the lines and printing the matching lines. But if there are any inputName which is not found in the log file, I need to print "File is not processed" only for that particular inputName.

Comment: Please add your sample test.log. The code looks OK.

Comment: I don't quite understand the `elif m: print "File not updated"` (while I now understand the other part of the problem), so in what situation should this be printed?

Comment: The scenario is that there will be files which will be uploaded when detected. There might be chances that the files may be detected, but may not be uploaded because of any issues. So I want to track the files which are detected & uploaded, detected & not uploaded, not detected. Below is the format in log file:                                                              

2015-03-18 06:34:24.820  INFO --- xxxxxxx    : The /tmp/test/abc-16 is detected
2015-03-18 06:36:44.030  INFO --- xxxxxxx    : The /tmp/test/abc-16 file has been uploaded

Comment: 1st "if" is for both detected & upload. 2nd "if" is only if the file is detected but no successful_msg is found for that file & 3rd "if" is that the filename is never present in log file. 

I'm able to get the desired output if elif statements are commented. If uncommented, even the scenario passed in 1st if will show as failed.

Comment: @Yadunandana Ok, can you please put this in your question? Please put at least one example file that would print match, one that would be 'File not updated' and one that would print 'File is not processed'. With your current `def`, any of the 3 will be printed for each line read by it.

Comment: You realize that the `inputName` in the code is different than the sample log file, right? I can say that the code is OK.

Comment: Updated the question. @Simurg, the inputName is dynamic for each files in the folder and I had just hardcoded only for this purpose. The code is edited and updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following change to your `def`, with my comments:

```
import re

successful_msg="file has been uploaded"
def log_check(fileName):
     search_fileName = fileName
     print search_fileName
     with open("/tmp/test.log") as line:
         # New variable to determine if fileName is matched or not
         matched = 0
         for match in line:
                 m = re.search(r"%s" %search_fileName, match)

                 # If fileName found, update above variable
                 if m:
                      matched = 1

                 n=re.search(r"%s" %successful_msg,match)

                 # On any line, if both phrases are present on the same line:
                 if n and m:
                      print match
                      break

         # If for loop exited without break...
         else:
              # If we found the filename...
              if matched == 1:
                  print "File not updated"
              # If even the filename was not found...
              else:
                  print "File is not processed"



for inputName in glob.glob('./files/*'):
    log_check(inputName)
```

Comment: @Yadunandana You're welcome! Please mark the answer as accepted to also mark your problem as solved :)